# Running docker-compose up ends up with error "Service has neither an image nor a build context specified."

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My microservices project structure is like this:

```
my-service-one/
  - Dockerfile
  - ...
my-service-two/
  - Dockerfile
  - ...
docker-compose.yml
```

As you can see, each service directory contains a Dockerfile. There is a `docker-compose.yml` in the root level.

The `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: "3"
services:
  service-one:
    container_name: service-one
    build:
      dockerfile: ./my-service-one/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
  
  service-two:
    container_name: service-two
    build:
      dockerfile: ./my-service-two/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
```

Now, I run `docker-compose up -d` from the root. I end up with error:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
ERROR: The Compose file is invalid because:
Service service-one has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.
```

My question is **why** does docker-compose think my `service-one` doesn't have a build context specified? Didn't I specify it already with:

```
build:
  dockerfile: ./my-service-one/Dockerfile
```

Why this error?

Comment: Can you add your docker file for the service 1? You might not have any docker image description in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does docker-compose think my service-one doesn't have a build context specified?

Weeeell, because you did not specified the build context.

> Didn't I specify it already with:

No, you specified the dockerfile. No the context.

> Why this error?

You have to specify the context so that docker knows what to build.

If you want to build with the context of current directory, you would do:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: ./my-service-two/Dockerfile
```

Maybe the context is inside `my-service-two`, I suspect youw antto write:

```
build:
  context: ./my-service-two
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

or really just:

```
build: ./my-service-two
```

Answer (score 0):

Peovide a context property below both services in build section like that:

```
build:
      context: YOUR_DIRECTORY
      dockerfile: ./my-service-one/Dockerfile
```

YOUR_DIRECTORY is the place where the files for your project are listed.

Most probably YOUR_DIRECTORY is already written i  the child .yml files.

You have a couple of main approaches:

- To copy paste the context from the child .yml
- To produce the docker build using the child .yml with a command like:

> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-dev.yml up
> --build